# is there a latex font correspond to the symbol, an X with bars at the top and bottom?

Tags: fonts

This professor is [using](https://youtu.be/p4wlQnZcBrg?t=3730) this symbol to denote the input space.

[image]

an X with bars at the top and bottom, is there a latex font correspond to the symbol?

I've tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html),

[image]

didn't get any luck.

Comment: You could try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to draw your symbol.  I did it, but was not able to get any hints.  Good luck!

Comment: That’s not a special symbol, but just an X. I’ve seen several people writing it like that *on the blackboard*, probably for distinguishing it from `\times`.

Comment: @egreg So, is there a latex symbol to render that in computer?

Comment: @JJJohn Not sure what you mean: you render it with `X`.

Comment: By the way, if you notice, in the last line the X has no bars and it represents exactly the same quantity.

Answer (score 3):

Using the package [`romanbar`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm7eo.png) (`\usepackage{romanbar}`), it is possible to obtain an `X` with bars at the top and bottom. I hope that the symbol is good for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{romanbar}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\Romanx{\mathord{\Romanbar{10}}}
\begin{document}
\Romanbar{10}, \verb|It is used in text-mode|

\[\abs{\Romanx}=2^{1000}, \verb|It is used in math-mode|\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no such symbol on the blackboard. It's simply an uppercase “X” that some people adorn on the blackboard with bars perhaps in order to distinguish it from ⨉.

If you look closely, the same symbol for the cardinality of X is used at the exponent of 2, and the X has no ornament.

Nothing special: it's just an X.